# XMLHttpRequest blocked in draw.io Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, draw.io

I am desperatly trying to code a plugin for Draw.io that will basically do a request to another website in order to get some images.

It works fine on the local web version of Draw.io, but on the desktop version I get an empty responseText.

Here is what I'm simply doing in the plugin js:

```
Draw.loadPlugin(function(ui)
{
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");

xhr.send();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    alert(this.responseText);
    }
});
});
```

That is pretty basic and probably not working well but I should at least get an error... All I have is an empty response.

Does the Electron app blocks outside XHR? Is there a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: do you get any errors on the console ?

Comment: I don't have access to the console unfortunately, the draw.io app does not allow it...

Comment: I cloned and installed the drawio-desktop git on my desktop, the issue is a classical "VM522:4 Refused to connect to #### because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'"".
I'm now looking for a way to allow cross requests in draw.io...

Comment: try adding the following to your index.js      const win = new BrowserWindow({
      ...
      webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
    });